# Cannot see honeycomb image in SDK manager

Tags: android

I am not able to see the honeycomb image available for download in SDK Manager. I am running Windows 7 x86.

Any ideas ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download the "SDK Platform" for Honeycomb. It includes the ARM system image.

Apparently it's only for newer API levels that the downloads are separate.